# Capturar click izquierdo del ratón en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eventos, click

¿Alguien puede decirme como capturar el click del ratón?

Este es lo que tengo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

event = Controller()

event.press(Key.alt)
time.sleep(0.1)
event.press(Key.tab)
event.release(Key.tab)
if <boton izquierdo raton pulsado>:
     event.release(Key.alt)
```

Muchísima gracias, utilizo Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido a SOes c:

Yo uso Windows 10, pero espero que aun así sirva mi respuesta.

Hice un pequeño código que cada vez que ocurre un clic (en este caso clic es que un botón del mouse se presione o deje de presionarse), actualiza un diccionario que tiene cada botón del mouse asociado a un boleano.
La buena noticia es que usa el mismo módulo que usas para capturar y crear eventos de teclado.

```
from pynput import mouse

mouse_pressed = dict.fromkeys((mouse.Button.left, mouse.Button.right, mouse.Button.unknown), False)

def OnClick(x, y, button, pressed):
    mouse_pressed[button]=pressed

mouse.Listener(on_click=OnClick).start()
        
while True:
    if(mouse_pressed[mouse.Button.left]):
        print("boton izquierdo presionado")
```

Nota: El código no trata correctamente casos donde el usuario mantenga presionado un boton antes de que el programa inicie. Para el código, el boton del mouse no estará presionado.

Comment: Muchisima gracias!!! es perfecto!